# Iterating through a nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having trouble trying to get my nested object to loop. The issue is it doesn't even hit the loop, like there's no values to loop through. I've looked through several posts and tried what they had to say and it's not even making it into the loop. Below is the code i'm using, any help would be awesome.

```
// json string being parsed
var objString = '{ "error": "no crontab for ec2-user "}}{ "accounts" : { "demo": { "Name": "Your Medical Clinic", "groupid": "demo", "CallerID": "8664738160", "CallerID_err": "OK", "TransferPhone": "1-931-555-1212", "TransferPhone_err": "INVALID LENGTH", "TimeZone": "EST", "EMRSoftware": "Greenway", "merlin": 1, "prm": 1, "CallDaysOut": 2, "EmailDaysOut": 5, "enablevoice": 1, "enabletext": 1, "enablemail": 1, "Exclude": "12 Months,12-17 Years,18+ Years,2 Months,", "emailBtnConfirm": 1, "emailBtnReschedule": 1, "emailBtnCancel": 1, "enablenoshow": 1, "enablecollection": 0, "enablerecall": 1, "enableapptalert": 1, "AppendCallerID": "Confirm,Cancel,Resched,AnsMach", "EmailReport": "kevin@relatient.net,john@relatient.net,hello@gim.com", "EmailReport_err": "OK", "SurveyReport": "chris@relatient.net", "SurveyReport_err": "OK", "HMReport": "john@relatient.net,kevin@relatient.net", "HMReport_err": "OK", "ApptReminders" : { "cronCalls": { "cronCalls_570": { "StartHour": 18, "StartQtrHour": 0, "StartTime_local": "7:00 PM EST", "EndHour": 19, "EndQtrHour": 0, "EndTime_local": "8:00 PM EST", "CallDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } }, "cronEmail": { "cronEmail_110": { "hour": 18, "qtrhour": 99, "StartTime_local": "INVALID EST", "ApptTimeMath": "", "EmailDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } }, "cronSMS": { "cronSMS_82": { "hour": 7, "qtrhour": 0, "StartTime_local": "8:00 AM EST", "DaysOut": 0, "cronargid": 1, "cronargid_type": "frombulk", "ApptTimeMath": "", "WorkDays": "MoTuWeThFr", "SendOnDays": "TuWeThFr", "cronSMS_err": "OK" } } }, "HealthMaint" : { "cronHMCalls": { "cronHMCalls_2": { "StartHour": 12, "StartQtrHour": 0, "StartTime_local": "1:00 PM EST", "EndHour": 16, "EndQtrHour": 0, "EndTime_local": "5:00 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoTuWeFrSa" } }, "cronHMEmail": { "cronHMEmail_1": { "hour": 3, "qtrhour": 3, "StartTime_local": "4:45 AM EST", "ActiveDays": "ThFrSa" } }, "cronHMSMS": { "cronHMSMS_1": { "hour": 2, "qtrhour": 2, "StartTime_local": "3:30 AM EST", "ActiveDays": "SuTuThSa" } } }, "MDPay" : { "cronMDPayCalls": { "cronMDPayCalls_2": { "hour": 15, "qtrhour": 3, "StartTime_local": "4:45 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoWeFr" } }, "cronMDPayEmail": { "cronMDPayEmail_2": { "hour": 13, "qtrhour": 1, "StartTime_local": "2:15 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoFr" } }, "cronMDPaySMS": { "cronMDPaySMS_2": { "hour": 15, "qtrhour": 1, "StartTime_local": "4:15 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "Su" } } }, "NoShow" : { "cronNoShowCalls": { } }, "Recall" : { "cronRecallCalls": { "cronRecallCalls_4": { "Hour": 11, "QtrHour": 0, "StartTime_local": "12:00 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } } }, "cronEmailReports": { "cronEmailReport_155": { "hour": 20, "qtrhour": 1, "StartTime_local": "9:15 PM EST", "DaysOut": 4, "csv": 1, "reportargid": 3, "reportargid_type": "calltime", "WorkDays": "SuMoTuThFrSa", "SendOnDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } }, "CallCntNotStatus99": 3680, "crontab": { }, "IncomingFiles": { "file_1": "payments.json", "file_1_changed": "2015-04-08 10:44", "file_1_lines": 222, "file_2": "recall.csv", "file_2_changed": "2014-04-17 08:58", "file_2_lines": 0, "file_3": "elerts.txt", "file_3_changed": "2014-12-11 14:14", "file_3_lines": 21, "file_4": "noshow.csv", "file_4_changed": "2014-04-17 08:44", "file_4_lines": 0, "file_5": "daily.txt", "file_5_changed": "2014-10-29 12:50", "file_5_lines": 188, "file_6": "bulk.csv", "file_6_changed": "2014-10-20 14:41", "file_6_lines": 1 } } }}';
```

Function looping through object

```
// example code to loop through object
var jsontext = objString.replace('{ "error": "no crontab for ec2-user "}}', '').trim(),
    obj = JSON.parse(jsontext);

console.log(obj);

if(typeof obj !== 'object') console.log('error'); return false;

// top level loop
$.each(obj, lp);

function lp(key, val) {
    // render table
    console.log(key);
    console.log(val);

    // recursion for children
    if(val !== null && typeof val === "object") 
        $.each(val, lp);
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trickell/keqk2aya/)

Comment: if statements should be enclosed in curly braces

Comment: @unikorn: That is a style choise, not a syntax requirement.

Comment: @guffa - not if it changes the logic - like above.

Comment: @Guffa, not when you have multiple statements

Comment: @Guffa true, but I think the `return false;` up there should be inside the `if` block which it isn’t.

Comment: @jamardi What field  exactly do you want to loop? I hope that from this day on you will use curly braces every time for if-else statements.

Comment: @McAden: Then it's a matter of some specific code that should be in brackets, not all code in an `if` statement.

Comment: @Guffa Both JSLint and JSHint recommend having all logic for `if`/`else` blocks inside of curly braces because of coding like the above. It's easy to make mistakes otherwise.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: Yes, they *recommend* it, but it's not a syntax requirement.

Comment: @Guffa it's a style choice for _single_ line if statements only, otherwise there is _no_ choice, you have to use braces. In OP's problem, it's the latter case.

Comment: @gitsitgo: You are missing the point. There is no such thing as a "single line if statement". An if statement is followed by a statement or a statement group. The braces is not required for the if statement, it's the syntax for a statement group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because your single line `if` statement. If you omit the curly braces, only the first line is part of the statement, so `return false;` is being executed every time:

With line breaks you can see your mistake:

```
if(typeof obj !== 'object') 
    console.log('error'); 

return false;

//Bunch of code that never gets hit
```

Comment: I think the reason I missed this is because the console.log('error') wasn't in the original code so before hand it was only the return false. Can't believe I'd make that mistake xD